# Electron shows blank screen after installing and using node-Sqlite3

Tags: vue.js, electron, node-sqlite3

well, after using node-sqlite3 my electron is showing blank screen on reload or whenever i change my code. Can anyone help me about this? why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it by adding the following in the background.js file:

```
function createMainWindow () {
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
 })

 // This code block is not related to the issue
 // I included it to demostrate how my app loads the index page
 if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
  if (!process.env.IS_TEST) { 
   mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools() 
  }
 } 
 else {
  createProtocol('app')
  mainWindow.loadURL('app://./index.html')
 }

 // Create listener that will handle the white screen issue
 mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   // Load the index URL the same way you load it above
   mainWindow.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
 })
```